# Mysql str_to_date(str, format) return null

Tags: mysql, datetime

Mysql str_to_date() return null.

```
mysql>  select str_to_date('15:30:00.000000', '%H:%i:%s.%f');
+-----------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('15:30:00.000000', '%H:%i:%s.%f') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

mysql 5.7.

Comment: It works for me. It says there was a warning, did you try reading it? What does it say?

Comment: `show warnings;` right after the select to see the warning

Comment: I can reproduce the NULL result in a DBFiddle on MySQL 5.7, but the same test results in a valid TIME value when I test on MySQL 8.0. Sounds like a bug that was fixed in 8.0. The fix may be to upgrade to 8.0, which you need to do by October 2023 anyway if you care to remain on a supported version of the product. Don't expect MySQL 5.7 to receive any more bug fixes.

Comment: note https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80064  (though the doc change mentioned there doesn't seem to be in place now, even for 5.7, and it does work in 8.0)

Comment: as a workaround, you can add a date and remove it: `select time(str_to_date(concat('1970-01-01 ','15:30:00.000000'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'));` https://dbfiddle.uk/qPspWaGC

Comment: show warnings: Incorrect datetime value: '15:30:00.000000' for function str_to_date

Comment: It worked before for 5.7.x.  Maybe the latest version 5.7.41 changed.